# javascript/jquery - object not able to itereate

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I got an object from a php page that spits out JSON that I have.  When I set a global variable equal to an object I create out of it and then try to get the data with a for(key in obj) loop it doesn't seem to work.

If I surround the for loop with something like a random $.post it works.  I am so confused as to why this happens.

Here's my code:

```
var myObj1 = new Object;

$(document).ready(function() {
$.post('namenums.php', {num : 1}, function(data) {
    var temp = $.parseJSON(data);
    for(var key in temp) {
        myObj1[key] = temp[key]['firstname'] + ' ' + temp[key]['lastname'];
    }
});

getStuff();
thing();
});

function thing() {
    for(var key in myObj1) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Now if I change my thing() function to something like this it works.

```
function thing() {
        $.post('random.php', function(data) {
    for(var key in myObj1) {
        console.log(key);
    }
        });
}
```

So, could someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: The first A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Sure. In the first example, `thing()` is being called when the document is ready--not necessarily after the AJAX call initiated by `$.post` has completed. In the second example, you aren't trying to log anything until the AJAX request is over, done, and results have been returned.

You could fix the first example by moving your call to `thing()` inside the callback provided to `$.post`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post('namenums.php', {num : 1}, function(data) {
    var temp = $.parseJSON(data);
    for(var key in temp) {
      myObj1[key] = temp[key]['firstname'] + ' ' + temp[key]['lastname'];
    }
    thing();
  });

  getStuff();
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  When you put it that way I don't see why I never realized that.